# how do i access ActiveRecord::Base globally throughout the OS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

after establishing this  `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML::load(File.open('config/database.yml')))`

without using rails framework i want to inherit the ActiveRecord::Base so i can have a model class?
what can you suggest?

what i did is I wrapped my model class into a single module and established a connection with the database and now my model classes can now inherit the ActiveRecord::Base....

Do you think its alright? What could be a good practice?

Comment: Just google "active record outside rails" -- here's a good start: http://blog.aizatto.com/2007/05/21/activerecord-without-rails/